# How to display different session status' on a profile page (guest view vs. user profile view)

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am creating a friend system where when the user visits another user's profile they see an **ADD FRIEND** option and when they visit their own profile they can see something else instead of the **ADD FRIEND** option like **TOTAL FRIENDS** (or similar) and when a guest visits (who is not logged in), they too see the page differently. To summarize, I need three views represented on one page:

1. When person is not logged in
2. When logged in `user != user_id`
3. When logged in `user == user_id`

As I have it now, something's gone wrong with how I set up my script. The sessions don't seem to be working under the proper instances.

**header.php:**

```
<?php 
include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user_login'];
}
else {
    $user = "";
}
?>
```

**profile.php:**

```
<?php include ( "./inc/header.inc.php" ); 

if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
        //check user exists
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($check)===1) {
            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username = $get['username'];
            $firstname = $get['first_name'];  
        }
        else {
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/tutorials/index.php\">"; 
            exit();
        }
    }
}

$optionbox = "";

if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']) != $user){
    $optionbox = '<div style="border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color:#999; font-size:11px;">
    <a href="#">Add friend</a>
    </div>';
}
else if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']) == $user){
    $optionbox = '<div style="border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color:#999; font-size:11px;">
    <a href="#">friend list</a>
    </div>';
}  
else {
    $optionbox = '<div style="border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color:#999; font-size:11px;">

    </div';
}
?>
```

Also tried using `['u']` instead of `user_login`,for first two situations both show either add friend or friend list in option box.

Comment: What does the error says here? Please specify. And where did you get that `$_GET['u']`?

Comment: you just said that you have `header.php` why is it you're including it like this `include ( "./inc/header.inc.php" ); `? Should you write it this way `include ( "./inc/header.php" ); `?

Comment: where did you define the `$user` here? I think there's no value for that in your code. the one you've used in all of your conditions.

Comment: In the spots you have `(isset($_SESSION['user_login']) == $user)` and the like, try `(isset($_SESSION['user_login']) && $_SESSION['user_login'] == $user)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that would help you. I have notated for clarity:

```
<?php
// Add connection here...(should be a PDO or mysqli_)
session_start();
// Add a simple true/false function to test for logged in
// Would be better included on this page rather than written (like connection)
function is_loggedin()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION['user_login']));
    }
// Make a function to test if the logged-in user is currently viewing own profile
// Would be better included on this page rather than written (like connection)
function is_profile($user = false)
    {
        if(!$user)
            return false;

        return (is_loggedin() && ($_SESSION['user_login'] == $user));
    }
// Presumably you would have profile.php?u=23432 or similar 
// If no user requested just assign false
$user   =   (!empty($_GET['u']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['u']))? $_GET['u'] : false;
// If the user is valid (not empty)
// Would be better included on this page if condition is met otherwise
// It just kind of loads extra lines for nothing
if($user != false) {
        // You should not be using mysql_ anymore, PDO or mysqli_ with prepared/bound statements
        $username   =   mysql_real_escape_string($user);
        //check user exists
        $check      =   mysql_query("SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($check) === 1) {
                $get        =   mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
                $username   =   $get['username'];
                $firstname  =   $get['first_name'];  
            }
        else {
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/tutorials/index.php\">"; 
                exit;
            }
    }
// Just do one wrapper
$optionbox[]    =   '<div style="border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color:#999; font-size:11px;">';
// Check if a user is logged in
if(is_loggedin())
    // If the logged in user matches the $_GET user
    $optionbox[]    = (!is_profile($user))? '<a href="#">Add friend</a>' : '<a href="#">friend list</a>';
// If user is not logged in
else
    $optionbox[]    =   '<h3>You must be logged in to view stuff and things</h3>';
// Finish wrapper
$optionbox[]    =   '</div>';
// Write to page
echo implode(PHP_EOL,$optionbox);
?>
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have a had a couple of upvotes on this answer since posting it originally, and I don't want to make references to things like *Add connection here...(should be a PDO or mysqli_)* without actually showing that so here is a little rewrite with proper connections and such. The `function.PDOConnect.php` is where your database credentials are populated:

*/classes/class.DBDriver.php*

```
<?php
// Have a general driver interface incase you need different database
// connection interfaces (MSSQL, etc)
interface DBDriver
    {
        public  static  function connect($user,$pass,$host,$dbname);
    }
```

*/classes/class.Database.php*

```
<?php
// Create MySQL PDO Connection based on the DBDriver preferences
class Database implements DBDriver
    {
        // This will store our connection for reuse
        private     static  $singleton;
        // This will store the connection options
        protected   static  $dbOpts;
        // This is the actual connecting to database
        public static   function connect($user,$pass,$host,$dbname)
            {
                if(isset(self::$singleton))
                    return self::$singleton;

                if(!isset(self::$dbOpts))
                    self::SetDatabaseAttr();

                try {
                        self::$singleton = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass, self::$dbOpts);
                        self::$singleton->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
                    }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                        echo "unable to connect to server";
                        exit;
                    }

                return self::$singleton;
            }
        // This sets the options for your database.
        public  static  function SetDatabaseAttr($value = false,$refresh = false)
            {
                if(!is_array($value) || empty($value)) {                        
                        self::$dbOpts[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]            =   PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
                        self::$dbOpts[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE] =   PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;
                        self::$dbOpts[PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES]   =   false;
                    }
                else {
                        if(empty(self::$dbOpts) || $refresh)
                            self::$dbOpts   =   array();

                        foreach($value as $DBKey => $DBValue)
                            self::$dbOpts[$DBKey]   =   $DBValue;
                    }

                return self::$dbOpts;
            }
    }
```

*/classes/class.QueryEngine.php*

```
<?php
// This class can be expanded out to do a lot more than just fetch from the database
class QueryEngine
    {
        protected   $query;
        private static  $singleton;
        // Create and Return instance of itself
        public  function __construct()
            {
                if(!empty(self::$singleton))
                    self::$singleton    =   $this;

                return self::$singleton;
            }
        // Basic query method
        public  function query($sql = false, $bind = false)
            {
                AutoloadFunction("PDOConnect");
                $con            =   PDOConnect();
                $this->query    =   $con->prepare($sql);

                if(!empty($bind)) {
                        foreach($bind as $key => $val) {
                                $bindVals[":{$key}"]    =   $val;
                            }

                        $this->query->execute($bindVals);
                    }
                else
                    $this->query->execute();

                return $this;
            }
        // This function is what returns the array in conjunction with
        // the query method
        public  function Fetch()
            {
                if($this->query) {
                        while($row = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $result[]   =   $row;
                            }
                    }

                return (!empty($result))? $result : 0;
            }   
    }
```

*/functions/function.AutoLoadClasses.php*

```
<?php
// This function is what is used to autoload classes on the fly
// There is no need to include class files, so long as they are in the
// /classes/ folder
function AutoLoadClasses($className) {
        if(class_exists($className)) {
                return;
            }

        if(is_file(CLASSES_DIR."/class.".$className.'.php')) {
                include_once(CLASSES_DIR."/class.".$className.'.php');
            }
    }
```

*/functions/function.AutoloadFunction.php*

```
<?php
// This will attempt to load the required file to run a specified function
// Similar to the autoloader for the classes, only this is required to be
// manually called like: AutoloadFunction("myfunction"); before function use
function AutoloadFunction($function = false,$loaddir = false)
    {
        if($function == false)
            return false;

        if(strpos($function,","))
            $functions  =   explode(",",$function);

        $function_dir   =   ($loaddir != false && !is_array($loaddir))? $loaddir.'/function.': FUNCTIONS_DIR.'/function.';

        if(!isset($functions)) {
                $functions[]    =   $function;
            }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($functions); $i++) {
                // Function name
                $addfunction    =   $functions[$i];
                // See if function exists
                if(!function_exists($addfunction)) {

                        $dir    =   $function_dir.$addfunction.'.php';
                        if(is_file($dir)) {
                                include_once($dir);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

*/functions/function.PDOConnect.php*

```
<?php
// Just make a quick PDO function to return your PDO Connection
// populate the arguements with your database credentials
function PDOConnect($user = "username",$pass = "password",$host = "hostname",$data = "databasename")
    {
        return Database::connect($user,$pass,$host,$data);
    }
```

*/functions/function.query_fetch.php*

```
<?php
// Here is a quick array fetching function using the query engine class
function query_fetch($sql = false,$bind = false)
    {
        $qEngine    =   new QueryEngine();
        return $qEngine ->query($sql,$bind)
                        ->Fetch();
    }
```

*/functions/function.is_loggedin.php*

```
<?php
// Add a simple true/false function to test for logged in
function is_loggedin()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION['username']));
    }
```

*/functions/function.is_profile.php*

```
<?php
// Make a function to test if the logged-in user is currently viewing own profile
function is_profile($user = false)
    {
        if(!$user)
            return false;
        AutoloadFunction("is_loggedin");
        return (is_loggedin() && ($_SESSION['username'] == $user));
    }
```

*/functions/function.get_profile.php*

```
<?php
// This will fetch the user based on a get variable
function get_profile($username = false)
    {
        // Presumably you would have profile.php?u=23432 or similar 
        // If no user requested just assign false
        $user                   =   (!empty($_GET['u']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['u']))? $_GET['u'] : false;
        $array['username']      =   false;
        $array['first_name']    =   false;
        // If the user is valid (not empty)
        // Would be better included on this page if condition is met otherwise
        // It just kind of loads extra lines for nothing
        if($user != false) {
                AutoloadFunction("query_fetch");
                //check user exists
                $get      =   query_fetch("SELECT `username`, `first_name`,`ID` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :0",array($user));

                if ($get != 0) {
                        $array['username']      =   $get[0]['username'];
                        $array['ID']            =   $get[0]['ID'];
                        $array['first_name']    =   $get[0]['first_name'];

                        return ($username)? $array['username'] : $array; 
                    }
                else {
                        header("location: http://localhost/tutorials/index.php"); 
                        exit;
                    }
            }

        return $array;
    }
```

*config.php*

```
<?php
// Define some basic locational constants
define("ROOT_DIR",__DIR__);
define("CLASSES_DIR",ROOT_DIR."/classes");
define("FUNCTIONS_DIR",ROOT_DIR."/functions");
// Load up the functions autoloader
include_once(FUNCTIONS_DIR."/function.AutoloadFunction.php");
// Load up the function for class autoloading
AutoloadFunction("AutoLoadClasses");
// Apply the autoloader for classes
spl_autoload_register('AutoLoadClasses');
```

*profile.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
// Load all the settings to make things work.
include(__DIR__."/config.php");
?>
<div style="border:#CCC 1px solid; padding:5px; background-color:#E4E4E4; color:#999; font-size:11px;">
<?php
// Using the "AutoloadFunction" should save execution time because
// it will only load functions it needs instead of loading all the functions 
// it could "potentially" need.
AutoloadFunction("is_loggedin");
// Check if a user is logged in
if(is_loggedin()) {
        AutoloadFunction("get_profile,is_profile");
        // Fetch the profile of current user query
        $user           =   get_profile();
        // If the logged in user matches the $_GET user
        echo (!is_profile($user['username']))? '<a href="?action=add&u='.$user['ID'].'">Add '.ucwords($user['first_name']).'</a>' : '<a href="#">friend list</a>';
    }
// If user is not logged in
else {
?>
    <h3>You must be logged in to view stuff and things</h3>
<?php }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this line I made a mistake on. Should be: `$user = (!empty($_GET['u']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['u']))? $_GET['u'] : false;`

Comment: Sure, do you have it exactly as I have it above?

Comment: Are you familiar with using objects (classes)? Using a class would be a better fit I think here. Same approach, but it's better contained.

Comment: Will be greatly thankful to you if you could help me on this, just added new code for follow system   `<?php
  $my_id = $_SESSION['user_login'];
  $u_id = $user;
 if($u_id !=$_SESSION['user_login']) {
   $check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM follow WHERE user_one='$my_id' AND user_two='$u_id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check) == 1){
      echo "<a href='actions.php?action=Unfollow&u_id=$u_id'>Unfollow</a>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<a href='actions.php?action=Follow&u_id=$u_id'>Follow</a>";
    }
   }
?>`   but in this new code i get undefined index for user login only when (not logged in),.

Comment: Are you around? Maybe doing email would be better than here.